# Namespace convention for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, namespaces

I'd like to group classes so they must be referenced like this:

```
Root.Web
Root.Mail
Root.Audio
```

Each of the above classes corresponds to a file:

```
Web.h
Mail.h
Audio.h
```

The goal is to use the above "Root" syntax rather than just:

```
Audio myAudio = [[Audio alloc] init];
```

Instead, it should look like:

```
Root.Audio myAudio = [[Root.Audio alloc] init];
```

Is Objective-C capable of doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objective-c doesn't support namespaces (as c doesn't) so you can't do that. To avoid potential collisions you can add your specific prefix to a class name
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021035/are-namespace-collisions-really-an-issue-in-objective-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178434/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-an-objective-c-namespace-collision) are the similar questions, may be you'll find them useful.

btw I think that if namespaces were supported they were addressed more in cpp-like way (like MyNamespace::MyClass, not MyNamespace.MyClass)

Answer (score 4):

Not to my knowledge, what you would do in Objective-C (or C) to achieve that is to namespace the class name instead.

```
RootAudio *myAudio = [[RootAudio alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose that is the prefix naming convention mentioned in a later posting.

Comment: Exactly, and if you look at the built in classes in Cocoa they use for example NS (NextStep), CA (CoreAnimation) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Although Objective-C might be capable of doing that, if you make Root a singleton with predeclared or dynamically built properties, I would really recommend against it.

It goes against the standard of Objective-C. It shouldn't be necessary to use such a method.

Every language is constructed in a certain way and should be used accordingly. The above is not how objective-c is meant to be used.

Why would you want to use it that way?

If it is so that every object can access Root.Audio, in order to play a file, then why not make Audio a singleton, or have a class method on Audio that can store and retrieve instances that you have declared? Every object in your run-time can access class methods..